# PHP Silex - Service Controller - passing a parameter

Tags: php, rest, service, controller, silex

According to :

[Silex - Service Controller Doc](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.0/providers/service_controller.html)

I can define a route like this (after a couple of extra code of corse):

> $app->get('/posts.json', "posts.controller:indexJsonAction");

But ... how can I pass the url used to the indexJsonAction function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be mapping that directly to the route, such as:

```
$app->get('/posts.json/{param1}/{param2}, 'posts.controller:indexJsonAction');
```

This way, in your controller, you can expect those parameters:

```
public function indexJsonAction($param1, $param2) {
    //now you have access to these variables.
}
```

Furthermore, silex uses Symfony's request under the hood, so you could also just inject the Request into the controller and get any input from the Request;

```
public function indexJsonAction(Request $request) {
    // use $request->get('param1'); etc
}
```

Comment: Great, Thanks very much.